# Adding labels information in k-core decomposition

Tags: python, networkx

I would need to visualize labels in a network where I extract kcore information.
The dataset is

```
Source  Target  Edge_Weight Label_Source    Label_Target
0   A   F         29.1  0.0 0.0
1   A   G         46.9  0.0 1.0
2   A   B         24.4  0.0 1.0
3   C   F         43.4  0.0 0.0
4   C   N         23.3  0.0 1.0
5   D   S         18.0  1.0 0.0
6   D   G         67.6  1.0 0.0
7   D   B         37.2  1.0 1.0
8   D   E         46.9  1.0 2.0
```

For extracting kcore information I used the code

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Source', 'Target')

kcore=nx.k_core(G)

plt.subplot(122)
nx.draw(kcore)

plt.show()
```

Do you know I can add the label information?
My expected value would be a graph which has colors based on their labels (it does not matter which color to assign to distinct labels values. The values are 0, 1, 2).

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do what you want is to create a colormap and associate it to your node label. You can then use the `node_colors` argument from the `nx.draw` function to set up the color of the nodes. Additionally, you can use `plt.scatter` to create empty plots to set up a legend for your labels in your graph.

See code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import cm

df=pd.read_fwf('graph.txt') #Stored your dataset in a file called 'graph.txt'
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Source', 'Target')
kcore=nx.k_core(G)
N_colors=3
cm_dis=np.linspace(0, 1,N_colors) 
colors = [cm.viridis(x) for x in cm_dis]
color_nodes=[]

for node in kcore:
    #Finding out label of the node
    temp_src=df.index[df['Source'] == node].tolist()
    temp_targ=df.index[df['Target']==node].tolist()

    if len(temp_targ)!=0:
      label=df['Label_Target'][temp_targ[0]]
      color=colors[int(label)]
    elif len(temp_src)!=0:
      label=df['Label_Source'][temp_src[0]]
      color=colors[int(label)]
    
    #Setting up legend
    if color not in color_nodes:
      plt.scatter([],[],color=color,label=str(label))

    color_nodes.append(color)

#Draw graph
nx.draw(kcore,with_labels=True,node_color=color_nodes)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]